# Проблема с сервером CS на centOS

Tags: centos

Вообщем есть сервер CS 1.6, он подымаеться сам если падает, сейчас он висит в воздухе, он не упал, но и не работает. Рут доступа нету ибо человек когда уезжал забыл его сказать. Как можно поднять сервер? А да забыл, есть скрипты *sh который должен убить процесс сервера, но когда я его запускаю, выбивает ошибку о том что ограничен доступ или каталога не существует.

Comment: ps ax |gpep srcd 1308 pts/5 S+  0:00 greb srcdkill -9 pidОтказано в доступеЕще варианты будут? Сервера проплачены, жалко в пустую :(

Answer (score 1):

Сервер физический? Попросите квм и загрузитесь в single-mode. Поменяйте рутовый пароль.Гуглите centos single mode.

Comment: Человек уехал отдыхать, квм мы не узнаем :( рутовый пасс тоже :( в singl mode он не запускается без рута и под sudo пользователь(я то бишь) не добавлен.

Comment: т.е. сервер стоит у этого человека дома?))ну тогда никак. Надо иметь либо рутовый доступ, либо физический к машине (хотя бы через IP-KVM)

Answer (score 0):

```
ps ax |grep srcdkill -9 pid
```